# Multiline label with different font styles and IBActions

Tags: ios

A perfect example of what I am trying to do is the Instagram comments.

Suppose we have a user and a list of text (the comment). I want my `UIView` to have the username in some font style and clickable along with text next to it and wrapping around to the next line (which is not clickable).

It might be easier to understand if you just look at this:

[image: instagram image]

Notice how the username is clickable and separated from the text, but the text wraps around to the next line. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at NSAttributedString?

Comment: Interesting. NSAttributedString look like half of it. But how can I make different parts of the string clickable?

Comment: Probably a few ways of skinning that cat: 1) using a gesture recognizer and checking the location, 2) set it up as it's own control whereby you can pickup the touch event, etc., etc., etc.